# Pricing MySQL Issue (group by)

Tags: mysql, group-by

**Problem Overview**

We have a website which compares multiple different prices for the same car model and we would like to display the models in ascending order of the cheapest available price.

**Schema**

The problem involves three tables (simplified for ease of understanding)

**Models**

[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPTHm.png)

**Ordering models by cheapest available price**

A model will have many derivatives and each of these derivatives will have many prices. We are looking to order the models by the minimum price available for any of their derivatives.

**This query**

```
select `models`.name, `prices`.`rental` from `models` inner join 
`derivatives` on `derivatives`.`model_code` = `models`.`code` inner 
join `prices` on `prices`.`cap_id` = `derivatives`.`cap_id` order by 
`rental` asc limit 15 offset 0;
```

will result in the following (which is almost correct)

[result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Z5H.png)

but obviously we only want to show one result per model. If we try to add a group by clause the minimum price is lost since MySQL picks an entry at random. Their documentation explains:

“However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. “

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html

**So this query**

```
select `models`.name, `prices`.`rental` from `models` inner join 
`derivatives` on `derivatives`.`model_code` = `models`.`code` inner 
join `prices` on `prices`.`cap_id` = `derivatives`.`cap_id` group by 
`models`.`code` order by `rental` asc limit 15 offset 0;
```

results in the following as an you can see the rental shown for the SANDERO HATCHBACK is not the minimum found earlier

[results2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j862.png)

Comment: Don't include pictures of text. Include text.

Comment: Order by `min(rental)`

Comment: Well also return the minimum in results rather then the randomly selected aggregate value.

Answer (score 0):

```
select `models`.name, min(`prices`.`rental`) from `models` inner join 
`derivatives` on `derivatives`.`model_code` = `models`.`code` inner 
join `prices` on `prices`.`cap_id` = `derivatives`.`cap_id` group by 
`models`.`code` order by min(`rental`) asc limit 15 offset 0;
```

Select the minimum value for rental -- this will display the minimum value in the result.
Order by the minimum value for rental -- this will place it in the correct position in the result.